# Is Repeatedly Calling DataContext.GetChangeSet() Performant?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I can't seem to find documentation about the performance of the GetChangeSet() function of LINQ-to-SQL's DataContext class. I see a lot of code in our own organization and posted around the web making repeated calls to GetChangeSet() as if it had no performance impact (rather than caching the value from the first call). I know it *can* do a significant amount of work, but is that skipped on subsequent calls? How concerned should I be during code review if I see GetChangeSet().Inserts referred to in a loop, for example? How much effort should be put into caching the result of GetChangeSet in cases where caching is not a simple matter?

Comment: I think caching the value is dangerous. The value returned by GetChangeSet() could easily change. For that same reason, internally GetChangeSet() does its full load of work every time you call it. I think a better solution is rethinking WHY GetChangeSet() is being called frequently.

Comment: @hatchet It shouldn't need to do any work if no tracked objects have been touched. And there are many cases where I can easily know that no tracked objects have been touched. For example, consecutively getting the Inserts, Updates, and Deletes collections from the ChangeSet.

Comment: Have you done any profiling to see if the amount of time to call GetChangeSet is worth worrying about for your typical use of DataContext (since the execution time is likely very dependent on the number of objects being tracked internally)?

Comment: @hatchet I have not done any profiling because my purpose in asking this question is to determine whether I should be concerned during code reviews in general when I see a case where GetChangeSet might be getting called frequently. And I fear if I profile one case I will not be covering all situations whose code I might review. So I would prefer to understand it at a higher level. I can't be profiling every bit of code I review so I really need to understand when I need to be concerned without the "blind" results of a profile of a specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect repeated calls to be performant at all.

According to the [method's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx), `GetChangeSet()` recalculates the list on every single call.

Comment: So the way that Shaul answered his own question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421012/preventing-recursion-during-datacontext-submitchanges was doing some very bad things in that he could have easily cached the result of GetChangeSet to collect Inserts, Deletes and Updates from it, but instead he called it 3 times (and many more) unnecessarily? I would have hoped that DataContext would have some mechanism of noticing that no tracked changes had occurred since the last call and not have to do as much work.

Comment: I don't believe that database round-trips are one of the side effects of GetChangeSet based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx. Do you have any evidence to support this?

Comment: @BlueMonkMn You're right.  I misread the first bullet point in the Remarks section.  Edited to fix.

Comment: I also don't believe that there is no guarantee that two consecutive calls will return the same results. Based on the last bullet, "The set of changed objects is computed at the time of the call. Subsequent calls to SubmitChanges can produce a different set if additional changes are made." So I expect that consecutive calls (where no additional changes are made) should return the same results.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN - "I would have hoped that DataContext would have some mechanism of noticing that no tracked changes had occurred since the last call and not have to do as much work." Looking with Reflector, it does not appear to have the mechanism you're hoping for. You can do a simple timed test of this. Read in a lot of rows (>=100,000), modify a bunch of them, then compare the time to execute back to back GetChangeSet calls to see if the second call is faster than the first.